# AlpineJS hour countdown shows negative value instead of hour value

Tags: javascript, datetime, alpine.js

I have this function made this AlpineJS. It is meant to take an input set in a backend of a shopping system and show a countdown to that input. If the input in the backend is 16:00 and the time now is 15:00, the countdown should say "59m 59s" until the time hits 16:00 where it will then say 23t 59m 59s and show on. It works semi-fine but after about an hour or so the function displays the seconds passed since 16:00 in a negative value instead of the actual countdown.

Entire function here:

```
window.shippingAlert = (
    days,
    time,
    offdays,
) => ({
    days: [],
    offdays: [],
    offDates: [],
    hour: '',
    minute: '',
    nextShipmentUnix: null,
    timeLeftString: "",
    init() {
        this.days = days.replace(7, 0).split(',').map((x) => parseInt(x)).sort(); // replace 7 (sunday) with 0 to match JS dates.

        let offDaysArray = offdays.split(',');

        this.offDates = [];

        for (let i = 0; i < offDaysArray.length; i++) {
            let dateParts = offDaysArray[i].split("-");
            let year = parseInt(dateParts[0]);
            let month = parseInt(dateParts[1]) - 1;
            let day = parseInt(dateParts[2]);
            this.offDates.push(new Date(year, month, day));
          }

        console.log(this.offDates)
                  
        let timeParts = time.split(':');
        this.hour = parseInt(timeParts[0]);
        this.minute = parseInt(timeParts[1] || 0);

        this.calculateNextShipment();
        this.calculateTimeLeft();

        window.setInterval(() => this.calculateTimeLeft(), 1000);
    },
    calculateNextShipment() {
        let currentDate = new Date();
        let currentDay = currentDate.getDay();
        let currentHour = currentDate.getHours();
        let currentMinute = currentDate.getMinutes();
      
        let nextDay = currentDay;
      
        // If time is passed, move to next days
        if (nextDay > this.hour || (currentHour === this.hour && currentMinute >= this.minute)) {
          nextDay = nextDay === 6 ? 0 : (nextDay + 1);
        }
      
        // If no shipments occur on the day, move on until the next available day
        if (!this.days.includes(nextDay)) {
          nextDay = this.days.filter((day) => day > nextDay)?.[0] || this.days[0];
        }
      
        // If there are specific dates where shipments do not occur
        let nextDate = new Date();
        let isOffDate = true;
        while (isOffDate) {
          nextDate.setDate(nextDate.getDate() + (nextDay >= currentDay ? (nextDay - currentDay) : (7 - currentDay + nextDay)));
          nextDate.setHours(this.hour);
          nextDate.setMinutes(this.minute);
          nextDate.setSeconds(0);
      
          isOffDate = this.offDates.some((offDate) => offDate.getDay() === nextDate.getDay());
          if (isOffDate) {
            nextDay = this.days.filter((day) => day > nextDay)?.[0] || this.days[0];
          }
        }
      
        console.log(nextDate);
      
        this.nextShipmentUnix = Math.floor(nextDate.getTime() / 1000);
      },
      calculateTimeLeft() {
        let currentTimeUnix = Math.floor(new Date().getTime() / 1000);
        let secondsLeft = this.nextShipmentUnix - currentTimeUnix;
      
        if (secondsLeft <= 0) {
          this.calculateNextShipment();
          currentTimeUnix = Math.floor(new Date().getTime() / 1000); // Update the current time
          secondsLeft = this.nextShipmentUnix - currentTimeUnix;
        }
      
        let parts = [];
      
        let days = Math.floor(secondsLeft / 86400);
      
        if (days > 0) {
          secondsLeft = secondsLeft - (days * 86400);
          parts.push(days + 'd');
        }
      
        let hours = Math.floor(secondsLeft / 3600);
      
        if (hours > 0) {
          secondsLeft = secondsLeft - (hours * 3600);
          parts.push(hours + 't');
        }
      
        let minutes = Math.floor(secondsLeft / 60);
      
        if (minutes > 0) {
          secondsLeft = secondsLeft - (minutes * 60);
          parts.push(minutes + 'm');
        }
      
        parts.push(secondsLeft + 's');
      
        this.timeLeftString = parts.join(' ');
      },
})
```

I have tried about everything and cannot resolve the problem. And by everything I mean literally everything.

Comment: Seemingly, something is going wrong in `calculateNextShipment` and it does not skip to the next day. Attach a debugger and step through this function and check where it goes wrong. One point that jumps into my eye: `if (nextDay > this.hour)`  doesn't seem to make much sense as `nextDay` hold the value for the weekday (ie 0 .. 6) and `this.hour` holds a value for an hour of the day ...

Comment: Please reduce your code to the minimum possible that still shows the error. Expecting others to run the code for over an hour to see the issue is expecting a bit much.